# pandas read IRS space-delimited txt data

Tags: pandas, txt

I recently was working with IRS tax file data. It is space-delimited txt data like the following (full data are [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shuai-zhou/DataRepo/master/data/C9091aki.txt)):

[image]

There are some patterns in the way the data was stored. But to me, the data is not formatted in a standard way and it is not easy to read into Pandas. I was wondering how to get a dataframe like the following from the above txt data:

```
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+-----+-----+-----+------+
| fips_state | fips_county |           name           | c1  | c2  | c3  |  c4  |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+-----+-----+-----+------+
|         02 |         013 | Aleutians East Borough T | 145 | 280 | 416 | 1002 |
|         02 |         016 | Aleutians West Total Mig | 304 | 535 | 991 | 2185 |
|        ... |         ... | ...                      | ... | ... | ... |  ... |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the data into columns in two separate dataframes within pandas or prior to creating your lists. After parsing merge the two dataframes.

```
import urllib.request  # the lib that handles the url stuff

target_url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shuai-zhou/DataRepo/master/data/C9091aki.txt'
list_a = []
list_b = []
for line in urllib.request.urlopen(target_url):
    if line.decode('utf-8')[0:2] != '  ':
        print(line.decode('utf-8').strip())
        list_a.append(line.decode('utf-8').strip())
    if line.decode('utf-8')[0:5] == '     ':
        print(line.decode('utf-8').strip())
        list_b.append(line.decode('utf-8').strip())
 
dfa = pd.DataFrame(list_a)
dfb = pd.DataFrame(list_b)
```